# How to read Spark SQL UserDefinedType from csv

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to define a UserDefinedType based on String but different from StringType in Spark 2.4.1 but it looks like there is a bug in Spark or I am doing smth incorrectly.

I define my type as follows:

```scala
class MyType extends UserDefinedType[MyValue] {
  override def sqlType: DataType = StringType
  ...
}

@SQLUserDefinedType(udt = classOf[MyType])
case class MyValue
```

I expect it to be read and stored as String with just a custom SQL type. In fact Spark can't read the string at all:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.UnivocityParser$$anonfun$makeConverter$11 cannot be cast to org.apache.spark.unsafe.types.UTF8String
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.BaseGenericInternalRow$class.getUTF8String(rows.scala:46)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GenericInternalRow.getUTF8String(rows.scala:195)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.JoinedRow.getUTF8String(JoinedRow.scala:102)
```

I think the problem is with UnivocityParser.makeConverter that doesn't return (String => Any) function but (String => (String => Any)) in the case of UDT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it is indeed a bug in Spark. I looked into Spark 2.4.1 sources and found the following:

```scala
case udt: UserDefinedType[_] => (datum: String) =>
  makeConverter(name, udt.sqlType, nullable, options)
```

changing this to

```scala
case udt: UserDefinedType[_] => 
  makeConverter(name, udt.sqlType, nullable, options)
```

solved my issue. Raised an issue for Spark: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-27591